# Mac should not take control of connected iDevice

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, itunes

Is there anyway to prevent the detection of iPod,iphone when it is connected to Mac.

The device should not be seen in iTunes,xcode,iPhoto or whatever app that detects the iDevices.

I tried writing the kernel with devices vendorId and manufacturerId which should take control of connected device but that does not work for iDevice but work for other CDC devices.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.